# php files on the fly

Tags: php, variables

In PHP, If i have this assign:

```
$link = 'Home';
```

And in another php section i need to grab the value of $link and insert it in a MYSQL query in plain text, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT txt FROM Home WHERE id = 1";
```

Note that $link has been written in the format of it's value in the query.
Basically i need to see the inside of the $link var and write it down on the query.

Why i need this -> because i'm creating php files on the fly after the click of a submit button.
And inside of the newly created file is a tinymce text editor that needs to read it's text contents from a table that was also created on the fly along with this file.

Comment: `i'm creating php files on the fly` could you clarify this? Usually when you have to create files/folders like this there is a better way to do things

Comment: Well, i have a form where i put the name of a file. After submit to a php action it creates a mysql table with the name of the file as also a new php file with a tinymce text editor that has a query to search text from the database table created after submission. I tried to use $_SESSION to the name of the table but when i close the browser the $_SESSION is lost and the tinymce editor lost it's focus on the database table. I need to put in the newly created file the name of the table where it is going to fetch data.

Comment: I'd recommend using a different solution. The one you are proposing is pointlessly complicated, insecure and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT txt FROM ".$link." WHERE id = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT txt FROM $link WHERE id = 1";
       ^                ^                 ^
```

The double-quotes (`"`) specify that the string has to be interpreted (with single quotes this won't work). Inside the string you can then write the name of the variable (`$link`) and it will be "supplanted" by its value.

I would'nt recommend doing this because it is vulnerable to SQL-injection and it is a very very bad practice that show that you do things in an uncommon way. Better avoid it!

---

**EDIT**: even worse...

When you say in a comment *creates a mysql table with the name of the file* that's an even worse thing to do. First, not all characters in a filename should go into a table name. Second, you can get litearlly **anything** as a filename, even things that are not actual filenames.

It is possible to **forge a HTTP request** so that the filename is an arbitrary string of your liking, for example:

```
a (); SELECT * FROM accounts; --
```

When you put this string into your query:

```
CREATE TABLE $filename (id int PRIMARY KEY, whatever varchar(20) NOT NULL);
```

You get this resulting SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE a (); SELECT * FROM accounts; -- (id int PRIMARY KEY, whatever varchar(20) NOT NULL);
```

As you can see, this will create a table `a` without any columns and then select all usernames and passwords, if the table `accounts` exists. The rest of the query is commented out with `--`.

This is a very simple SQL injection attack and you don't want to do this! Don't put userinput straight up into your SQL queries!!

---

**EDIT**: taking the value from `$_POST`

If your field has the name `link` then you can access it with

```
$_POST['link']
```

You can put this into your string this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT txt FROM {$_POST['link']} WHERE id = 1";
```

Comment: That is what i have, and the newly created file lost focus on later uses, becauses $link, comes from $_POST of the form.

Comment: Many thanks for all the advices, but in this scenario they don't work, maybe if .zip my project (it's small for now), and if you have the kindness and time, you could look at what i'm trying to do, and maybe see a fix for my problem.

Comment: If you can't see the project, no heart feelings :)

Comment: Sorry I already have a job. I help others out here on SO just for fun. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Ok. As i said no heart feellings. Have a nice working week :)